# Three of the Four Kinds of Volcanic Eruptions...Underwater

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, geology, volcanoes, lava

A volcanic eruption is measured in two constants--gas and viscosity.  For clearance, low viscosity is like squirting water off a nozzle, whereas high viscosity is like squirting caramel off a nozzle, which takes more effort to do, which makes it more dangerous.

In geology, there are four different kinds of volcanic eruptions:

1. Low Gas + Low Viscosity = A quiet lava flow.
   [image]
2. High Gas + Low Viscosity = A fire fountain eruption.
   [image]
3. Low Gas + High Viscosity = A dome-building eruption.  (This sort of eruption doesn't reach critical right away.)
   [image]
4. High Gas + High Viscosity = A Ring of Fire explosion.
   [image]

These sorts of eruption are impressive enough on land, but in the event of someone doing some serious worldbuilding, this question puts three of the four types underwater.  Type #1 has long been confirmed to happen underwater, but the oceanic differences in temperature and pressure have produced a different result called "pillow lava".

[image]

Is it possible for eruption types numbers 2, 3 and 4 to occur underwater?  If yes, then would the oceanic differences in temperature and pressure make them look and act differently from how they have acted above sea level?

Comment: Do you want the kinds of explosions that occur in 2, 3, and 4? Because I think that water pressure would limit how spectacular they are. Or it would make them happen way less but much, much more terrifyingly.

Comment: Please, attribute authors of images you are using, and make sure that they are CC-compatible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question purely about geology.

Comment: @StephenG, How can a question that is *literally* about worldbuilding be off-topic?  Please site a reason from the [help] to justify the VTC.

Comment: Author's choice people.  Feel free to suggest migrating to another site but being on-topic elsewhere doesn't make it off-topic here.

Comment: Lets be clear, "worldbuilding" does not mean answer my geology question.  We're not being asked to *build* anything here, nor to make a consistent world, or comment on one.  It's a straight question on geology.  That's **not** what worldbuilding is for,  It **is** what Earth Sciences SE is for.  Fewer and fewer questions on Worldbuilding seem to actually be for the intended purposes of the site and seem to be "What if ..?" and misc. science questions.

Comment: There does not appear to be a worldbuilding aspect to this question. It is based entirely on what happens in this world. There doesn't appear be fictional world that is being built, hence off topic (earth sciences would be a good migration target)

Comment: @James  Hear, hear!

Comment: @StephenG  So you're saying there are actual high-viscous high-gas underwater eruptions on Earth?  If there aren't, then this question won't be appropriate for Earth Science.

Comment: How on Earth questions about Earth sciences and Earth are now off topic on this site? As James said, being on-topic elsewhere doesn't make it off-topic here. This is the consensus or was apparently.

Comment: @StephenG, you just disqualified about 30% of the questions that are asked here.  I asked you to point to a [help] condition that made this question off-topic and you did not do so.  If you want to bring your opiniion to the Community for review, please post a question in Meta, but this question is not off-topic.

Comment: @JBH  Hear, hear!

Answer (score 3):

Underwater volcanoes have basaltic lava, which is poor in silicates. This means their lava is low viscosity, so you are pretty much limited to type #2.

However, since a low viscosity magma is also less capable of capturing gases on the long term, the only way to have low viscosity and high gas is a late mixing of water and magma with the resulting formation of high pressure steam.

Being underwater strongly reduce the bursting of steam, as water pressure can increasingly counter the steam pressure with increasing the depth.

That's why most of the observed type #2 eruptions happen closer to the surface, like in the [Isola Ferdinandea or Graham Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_Island_(Mediterranean_Sea)).

Answer (score 1):

First, for (2) and (4), the key element is decompression - volatiles (Mostly CO2 and H2O) coming out of solution as the pressure decreases.  However, the solubility increases exponentially with depth (unfortunately all the good links for this are pay-walled). So in any significant depth of water (more than a few hundred meters), these eruptions can't really happen because the magma can't decompress sufficiently.

For (4) as well, many of the effects of the eruption come from a column of superheated gas and ash that rises into the air in an [Pelean Eruption](https://www.britannica.com/science/Pelean-eruption). This then collapses to give pyroclastic flows. Obviously this won't happen underwater. In shallower water, you'd get a hot mix of water and ash, and some [submarine pyroclastic flows](http://www.d.umn.edu/~rmorton/ronshome/Volcanology/Subaqueous%20Pyroclastic%20Flows%202010%20Hudak.pdf).

(3) is interesting; but the presence of water would lead to explosive fracturing, and I suspect a block and ash flow as described above.

Overall you will see fewer if any actual explosions, but a lot of ash/block density-driven flows.

Comment: I've never seen a block-and-ash flow.